# Facebook Request.callback() not firing when request is made from Service

Tags: android, callback, facebook-android-sdk

I have a Service that uploads photos to a Facebook album, and it works fine. The problem is that the callback is never called (and the service is still alive...)

```
Request uploadPhoto = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), albumId + "/photos", 
params, HttpMethod.POST,new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
          //After upload to facebook succeeded, upload the data to the server.
          Log.d(" in calback!!! ", "");
});
uploadPhoto.executeAsync();
```

Comment: How do you know that it is working fine?

Comment: @verybadalloc photos are uploaded to my account on Facebook, just like I intended them to, to the correct album.

Comment: Accoding to the [executeAsync() docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#executeAsync%28%29), you need to run executeAsync from a UI thread. Can you try moving your code from a service to an Activity, just to test it out?

Comment: @verybadalloc From an activity the callback is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you have probably noticed, is that the [executeAsync()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#executeAsync%28%29) method needs to be called from a UI thread for the callback to work. A service, on the other hand, runs in the background, thus with no access to the UI thread.

Since I don't think you are planning to do any UI work in your onComplete(), one suggestion is to use a different API that does not require running on UI thread. One such API is [executeAndWait()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#executeAndWait%28%29), which will return a response object you can use for checking against errors. For example:

```
Response resp = uploadPhoto.executeAndWait();
if(resp.getError() == null){
    //Success
}
```

Comment: This helps with the callback, the problem is that the response is always {Response: responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false} and I need the graphObject...

Comment: @user2298443 In such a case, you should create a new question, since the proposed answer does solve the problem as stated.